# Is this Singapore school letter about exams real?

Tags: school, singapore, document-authenticity

This is doing the rounds [on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155059814177960):

[image]

> A school principal in Singapore sent this letter to the  parents before the exams
>
> Dear Parents
>
> The exams of your children are to start soon. I know you are all really anxious for your child to do well.
>
> But, please do remember, amongst the students who will be sitting for the exams there is an artist, who doesn't need to understand Math... There is an entrepreneur, who doesn't care about History or English literature... There is a musician, whose Chemistry marks won't matter... There's an athlete... whose physical fitness is more important than Physics... If your child does get top marks, that's great! But if he or she doesn't... please don't take away their self-confidence and dignity from them. Tell them it's OK, it's just an exam! They are cut out for much bigger things in life. Tell them, no matter what they score... you love them and will not judge them.
>
> Please do this, and when you do...watch your children conquer the world. One exam or a low mark won't take away...their dreams and talent. And please, do not think that doctors and engineers... are the only happy people in the world.
>
> With warm Regards

What makes me suspicious:

- it is not a photo of the letter;
- if you do a Google (image) search you'll find different layouts and variations in text, like the one below;
- grammar and punctuation;
- it is on [9gag](https://9gag.com/gag/an1nmYz/a-school-principal-in-singapore-sent-this-to-parents) signed "The principal".

[image]

Posts about this go back to at least 2014.

Comment: https://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/news/greater-manchester-news/stalybridge-school-sends-letter-sats-9224044 is a real letter sent by a Manchester school along the same lines, I don't know if it was inspired by the above or vice versa though.

Comment: I think the question did a pretty adequate job of debunking it actually.

Comment: @dont_shog_me_bro One possibility could be that it's a translation from the original.